# Test Angular $window.location.href in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out how to properly inject the $window service into my angular controller, and then test to make sure it redirects appropriately. Currently, I am getting an error stating `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/profile')')`. A snippet of my angular controller is as follows:

```
login.submitLogin = function(){
    LoginFactory.loginUser(login.dataset)
        .then(function(response){
            $window.location.href = '/profile'
        },function(response) {
            login.errorMessage = response.data.message;
        });
};
```

My unit test in Karma is as follows:

```
describe('Login Controller', function() {

    var controller, window;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$window_){
        window = _$window_;
        controller = _$controller_('LoginCtrl',window);
    }));

    describe('Login', function() {

        it('expects controller to be defined', function(){
            expect(controller).to.be.defined;
        });

        it('expects to be redirected after login', function() {
            controller.dataset.username = 'username';
            controller.dataset.password = 'password';
            controller.submitLogin();
            expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/profile');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `_$controller_('LoginCtrl', { $window: window })`. And mocked `$window` service can be supplied to controller instead of `window ` this way.

Comment: I changed my code to the following : `$window = _$window_;
        controller = _$controller_('LoginCtrl', { $window: window });` in the beforeEach. I injected `expect($window.location.href).toEqual('/profile')` and still get the exception. Do I need to mock the backend as Andrzej suggested?

Comment: `{ $window: window }` doesn't make sense because it is already equal to `window`. You need to stub `$window` with `{ location: {} }` object to not let the controller screw up `window` global, this is what it is about. If `LoginFactory` does http request then sure, you need to mock it, too. The preferable way to do unit tests to mock everything but tested unit (including `LoginFactory`).

Comment: So do you mean to say it should look like this?:
`controller = _$controller_('LoginCtrl', {location: {} });` and then in the expect: `expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/profile');`

Comment: Real `$window` shouldn't be injected at all in this case, it is just not needed. You mock it with `$windowMock = ...; _$controller_('LoginCtrl', { $window: $windowMock })` and then expect on `$windowMock.location.href`.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is just mock (overwrite) $window service in your tests:

```
    beforeEach(function () {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$window', {
                location: {href: ''}
            });
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$window_){
        window = _$window_;
        controller = _$controller_('LoginCtrl',window);
    }));
```

and then just check what has been assigned to $window.location.href by:

```
expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/profile');
```

also you need to use [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) if LoginFactory.loginUser makes request to server:

```
    it('expects to be redirected after login', function() {
        var mockedResponse = {};

        controller.dataset.username = 'username';
        controller.dataset.password = 'password';

        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/login/').respond(mockedResponse);
        controller.submitLogin();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/profile');
    });
```

Comment: It is just `module({ $window: { location: {href: ''} })`.